# Global Scale regardless of Resolution and Aspect Ratio?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I've recently started working on a small 2D Game Engine and was wanting to implement a fixed global scale for all of my objects. I'm using GLFW for my OpenGL library and GLM for my Matrix math.  What I'm thinking is something like this:

- All objects with scale of (1,1) should take up about 5% of the screen
- The object should only take up 5% of the screen regardless of resolution and aspect ratio
- i.e. a 1x1 square should only take up 5% if the screen is 1920x1080, 800x600, 1024x768 and so on...

I have: Screen Width, Screen Height, and Aspect Ratio

The math I'm thinking is basically:

```
glm::vec2 out_scale = glm::vec2(in_scale.x * (0.05f * SCREEN_WIDTH), in_scale.y * (0.05f * SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

My biggest hump is where to use the aspect ratio and how do I make sure a texture will scale with the object as well.

- i.e. a 1x1 square with a 16x16 texture or 32x32 texture won't clip

My Window Setup:

```
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "2D_Engine_Test", nullptr, nullptr);
```

My Viewport Setup:

```
glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

Comment: Are you looking to do this for objects in the game itself, or is this for a UI of some sort?

Comment: Objects in the game itself.

Comment: "All objects with scale of (1,1) should take up about 5% of the screen" sounds like you talk about 5% of the _area_ of your screen, while your code seems to scale both width and height to 5% individually. But be it as it may, you _can't_ have width and height a fixed percentage while at the same time keeping the aspect ratio. You have to give up at least one of the 3 constraints: width, height or aspect ratio. (currently, you do the third).

Comment: However, I think your way of looking at this is confused. I think it would make most sense if you keep aspect ratio out of your object sizes. You either use it so that on a wider screen, you will see a wider part from the overall scene, or you define a fixed aspect ratio for your output and just add black bars (or any kind of borders) if the screen aspect ratio does not match.

Comment: After experimenting all day I think I figured it out.  I was overthinking the entire thing.  Basically I created a global WORLD_UNIT value that was calculated by SCREEN_HEIGHT * WORLD_SCALE (I'm using 5% or 0.05f).  I then multiplied the scale and position matrices to give all of my objects a fixed base scale.  Basically now the objects render the same size across the board.  I am however thinking of creating an internal framebuffer so I can have an independent internal resolution that the game will render at but not sure if that's what I want right now.